# How to catch segmentation fault with Google Test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

How do I test that a function won't produce a segmentation fault?

Here what I know right now, I can do:

```
EXPECT_DEATH(foo(nullParameter))
```

In side the function, a segmentation fault is produce which is the behavior that I want to make fail. The snippet above will make the test pass because that is what is expected, the death of the process.

Now, how can I make it fail?

Comment: Other than not dying, I assume? You want what, a segfault that the tester misses?

Comment: It's too late once a segfault happens.  It's easier to prevent getting hit by a bus than it is to revive the dead.

Comment: The idea behind this is that I know that the function is causing a segfault and there will be a patch to fix this. Right now my goal is to make a test that fails before the path is made.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a function that will segfault if passed a null pointer argument and otherwise
not:

```
int deref(int * pint)
{
    return *pint;
}
```

And here is a googletest program that tests that behaviour:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int deref(int * pint)
{
    return *pint;
}


TEST(test_deref_1,will_segfault)
{
    ASSERT_EXIT((deref(nullptr),exit(0)),::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGSEGV),".*");
}


TEST(test_dref_2,will_not_segfault)
{
    int i = 42;
    ASSERT_EXIT((deref(&i),exit(0)),::testing::ExitedWithCode(0),".*");
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile and link:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o tester main.cpp -pthread -lgtest
```

Run:

```
$ ./tester 
[==========] Running 2 tests from 2 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from test_deref_1
[ RUN      ] test_deref_1.will_segfault
[       OK ] test_deref_1.will_segfault (168 ms)
[----------] 1 test from test_deref_1 (168 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from test_dref_2
[ RUN      ] test_dref_2.will_not_segfault
[       OK ] test_dref_2.will_not_segfault (1 ms)
[----------] 1 test from test_dref_2 (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 2 test cases ran. (169 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```

As far as I can imagine, `TEST(test_deref_1,will_segfault)` is a pointless test,
because I cannot think of any circumstances in which I would want to assure
myself that a program will segfault as a result of making a certain call to a
function I have written.

`TEST(test_dref_2,will_not_segfault)` is possibly a useful kind of test. In effect,
it is a test that the program:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    defref(&i);
    exit(0);
}
```

will terminate by `exit(0)` rather than in any premature abnormal way. A better name for
this test would probably be `TEST(test_dref,does_not_crash)`, or similar.

It is a possibly useful kind of test because there could be a significant risk of it
*failing*, if `defref` was some sufficiently complicated code, and the test suite
could report that failure without crashing itself. We can force a failure by rewriting
it:

```
TEST(test_dref_2,will_not_segfault)
{
    ASSERT_EXIT((deref(nullptr),exit(0)),::testing::ExitedWithCode(0),".*");
}
```

and then test test report is:

```
$ ./tester
[==========] Running 2 tests from 2 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from test_deref_1
[ RUN      ] test_deref_1.will_segfault
[       OK ] test_deref_1.will_segfault (147 ms)
[----------] 1 test from test_deref_1 (147 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from test_dref_2
[ RUN      ] test_dref_2.will_not_segfault
main.cpp:25: Failure
Death test: (deref(nullptr),exit(0))
    Result: died but not with expected exit code:
            Terminated by signal 11 (core dumped)
Actual msg:
[  DEATH   ] 
[  FAILED  ] test_dref_2.will_not_segfault (90 ms)
[----------] 1 test from test_dref_2 (90 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 2 test cases ran. (237 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] test_dref_2.will_not_segfault

 1 FAILED TEST
```

See [the documentation of `{ASSERT|EXPECT}_EXIT`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#how-to-write-a-death-test)
to understand these macros.

Comment: The documentation also puts a lot of emphasis about [not using underscores in test names](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md). You should probably refactor your code.

Comment: @Mike Kinghan But in case of a failure a core file still gets created, right?

Answer (score 0):

Tests which crash are already failures (presumably you don't want *any* of your code to segfault). Just test for the behavior you expect, as with any other test.

Comment: What I want is to test that the segment fault doesn't happen. For example I want to say something EXPECT_NO_DEATH, which implies that the code successfully execute.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleTest crashes when the tested program segfault, without producing a useful test report, so in general each test needs to be run in a subprocess.

One way to do that is to wrap all your tests to exit(0) and ASSERT_EXIT as described in the top answer.

However, a much more convenient way to do that is to use [gtest-parallel](https://github.com/google/gtest-parallel). With `gtest-parallel --serialize_test_cases --worker=1`, it just calls `gtest` as a subprocess, which solves the issue: segfaults get reported as test failures *without any changes in tests*. It's a wrapper for `gtest`, so it has mostly the same command line options as `gtest`.