# GoogleTest EXPECT_EXIT fails reporting exit code that was never called

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I want to test that my function does not crash when passed some specific parameters.

As suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583352/how-to-catch-segmentation-fault-with-google-test) I made the following test:

`EXPECT_EXIT({ cm.insert(-1, 0, &pt, 0); exit(0); }, ::testing::ExitedWithCode(0), ".*")`

However, the test fails with message

> Death test: { cm.insert(-1, 0, &pt, 0); exit(0); }     Result: died but not with expected exit code:             Exited with exit status 23 Actual msg: [  DEATH   ]

Investigating, I get to the following:

`EXPECT_EXIT(exit(0), ::testing::ExitedWithCode(0), ".*");`

fails with the same message:

> Death test: exit(0)     Result: died but not with expected exit code:             Exited with exit status 23 Actual msg: [  DEATH   ]

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

UPDATE: as suggested, I tried to reproduce it without any other libraries and the bug did not happen. Apparently, something else causes this behaviour, so the question is irrelevant.

Comment: You should not invoke `exit`. And in order to test that function does not crash `EXPECT_EXIT` is not required at all. If something crashes then test run fails automatically.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `exit` invocation causes destructors of objects with automatic storage duration and all the post-test logic to be skipped, potentially leading to unexpected results.

Comment: Can you reproduce your 2nd exit(0) error without using any libraries other than googletest? If yes, you may want to report this as a bug jn the googletest bug tracker.

Comment: As a workaround, you may want to call `_exit(0)` instead of `exit(0)`.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/E6r8365sE). Works with explicit call to `exit`, calling function that calls `exit`, and using `{multipleStatements();}` in a brackets. @user7860670 destruction of objects with auto storage and post-test logic is not a problem here. Gtest magic makes the STATEMENT inside a `EXPECT_EXIT` macro to be run as a child process, so when it exits, test body continues.

Comment: I don't really agree with SO answer that you quoted. First, nullptr dereference is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28573259/4165552), so that death test might pass or fail, which makes it quite useless. Second, like already mentioned here in the comments, if you want to test for "no crash", just run your code under test as is, if it crashes, the test will fail. Death tests feature is provided by gtest for the case where you test some exotic C++ code which doesn't throw exception on failure, instead calls `if(someThingWrong()) { std::exit(ERR_CODE); }`.

Comment: I understand, that crash of the program will lead to immediate test failure. However, I would like to
1. Receive a message where it fails instead of just default segfault message
2. Continue testing other cases

Comment: Your code seems to have other bugs in global and static objects deconstructions.